# Como Passar variável para dentro da função

Tags: php, laravel

Nesse script de envio de email "PHP Laravel" eu faço um loop para múltiplos envio.

O problema é que eu não estou encontrando a solução para passar as variavel "**$email**" dos posts para
dentro da função "**function($m)**"

Só estou conseguindo passar dessa forma  "define('EMAIL', $email);" mas no loop ela da erro
Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

```
public function disparo_em_massa(Request $campos) //contato
{

 foreach ($campos['id'] as $key => $value) {
 $contato = $_POST['contato'][$key];//
 $email = $_POST['email'][$key];// 
 $id = $_POST['id'][$key];// 



 define('EMAIL', $email);
 Mail::send('emails.recadatro_mail',[
   'id' =>$id ,
   'nome' => $contato , 
   'email' =>$email ], 

   
 function($m) {

   echo $email = EMAIL;
   $m->from('comercial@triplxx.com.br', 'Triplxx Receptivo');
   $m->to("$email");
   $m->returnPath('comercial@triplxx.com.br');
   $m->subject('Atualização Cadastral');
   $m->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Confirm-Reading-To: comercial@triplem.com.br');
   });

  }

 }
```

Comment: Cara, você ta misturando laravel com php cru, o laravel tem recursos precisar acessar o `$_POST` diretamente. O `Mail` também pode ser enviado para vários emails de uma só vez sem precisar realizar foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta utilizar o `use ()`, ficaria assim:

```php
 function ($m) use ($email) {
   $m->from('comercial@triplxx.com.br', 'Triplxx Receptivo');
   $m->to("$email");
   $m->returnPath('comercial@triplxx.com.br');
   $m->subject('Atualização Cadastral');
   $m->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Confirm-Reading-To: comercial@triplem.com.br');
   });
}
```

ref.: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.anonymous.php